# Set Default Path for Git Server

Tags: git, macos, unix

I'm trying to set up my own git server on a machine I'm playing around with at home. It's on OSX.

so far this works pretty well I can git clone from my other computer.

The annoying thing is that I need to clone like this:

`git clone ssh://git@[local-server-ip]/Users/git/myrepo.git`

I have to specify the full path where the repo sits.
What I really want is to have a default root path for all repos specified on the server such that I can clone like this:

`git clone ssh://git@[local-server-ip]/myrepo.git`

But I can't seem to figure out how. :-/